# He had his cavity treated with his mouth opened by the doctor. (Is this grammatically correct?)

Tags: sentence-construction

> He had his cavity treated with his mouth opened by the doctor.

(Is this grammatically correct?)

Comment: I'm not even sure what this is meant to mean.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not strictly *incorrect* in terms of grammar, but it is very ambiguous as to its meaning, and poorly constructed in general. For example, it could leave the reader unsure about the following:

1. Who actually treated the the patient’s cavity?
2. Who opened the patient’s mouth (was it the patient, or did the doctor open it for him)?
3. Was the patient’s own mouth used (as a tool) to treat the cavity?

At very least, you need some commas to make it clearer.  But it may be better to rephrase it from scratch.